# Wamp removing port from public ip

Tags: ip, wamp, port

I'm using wamp, and I'm trying to get a dydns for my domain to point to my ip.
I'm attempting to use FreeDns. Currently, my public site is xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080, however I don't think FreeDns will let me specify :8080, so how can I remove the port number from my public dynamic IP?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out domains and dns don't handle ports, and the default web server port is port 80, by swiching to port 80 in my router, and in my apache config, I was able to get my freeDNS account and my domain.com pointed in the right place.

Sorry for the noobish question :)